# Cache busting in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, caching, browser-cache

I'm trying to get a rough estimate of trip time to a server. I am currently doing this by loading an image and timing the time it takes. I do this 5 times and take an average. This actually gives me pretty accurate results BUT Chrome (haven't tried other browsers) still caches the page despite using a unique query string.

```
function rttTest() {
    rtt_count++;
    var startTime = new Date();
    var endTime;
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function () {
        if (rtt_count <= rtt_tests) {
            endTime = new Date();
            total_rtt = total_rtt + (endTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime());
            console.log(total_rtt);
            rttTest();
        } else {
            console.log((total_rtt / rtt_tests).toFixed(0));
        }
    };
    img.src = "http://the url/load.gif?v=" + startTime;
}
```

All the articles/posts I've read still list the unique query string as the way to bust cache but it doesn't work. In Chrome I have to HARD refresh and clear cache before it works again.

Are there any new ways that ensures a file is fetched for the "first time" each and every time?

To clarfiy, the FIRST get of the file is always correct. Say, for example, the first run through takes 150ms (that's spot on) but the other 4 in the loop take 1-2 ms, rather than 150 each time. I CAN use the value of just one test but I'd rather take an average.

Comment: u can load different image each time(copy same image several times and name them load1, load2 and iike this) but that isn't the answer to your main question - how to load same image again and again and not let it get cached?   :(

Comment: That wouldn't help too much as the page could get loaded/refreshed 1000s of times.

Comment: We completely change the name of our javascript files and chrome still doesn't check them somehow magically.   I can't understand how it does that